# Analyzing time complexity using recurrence relations

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, complexity-theory, recurrence

Complexity analysis noob here.

I'm trying to figure out the time complexity of a recursive algorithm using the given recurrence relation below -

```
T(n) = n + 4T(n/2)
```

There are three methods for this I know, but I'm trying to solve by summing the amount of work done at each level of the tree.

When I draw the recursion tree, I get the structure like this

```
                        n                          | n work
                     /     \
              4T(n/2)        4T(n/2)               | 2n work
             /     \         /        \
         4T(n/2)   4T(n/2)   4T(n/2)  4T(n/2)      | 4n work

          .          .          .       .
          .          .          .       .
     Theta(1) Theta(1) Theta(1).......Theta(1)     | ???
```

I'm stuck in calculating the sum ***(n + 2n + 4n + 8n ...)***
because

- I can't figure out the last term.
- Even if I did, I realize this is a Geometric series with ratio r>1, so I can't really calculate the sum.

Could someone please help me understand how to go about this?

**Edit**
Note: I found the problem from here - http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/Personal/Rolf_Karlsson/lect1.pdf where there is a solution but I don't exactly follow it and it seems like my expression is at least correct, but I can't follow how the last term is gotten.

Comment: Hello, I'm going through the concepts, I will get back to this answer in a bit and see which one makes better sense to me. I understood as to what both the answers are talking about, but I have yet to make *exact* sense of the minute details... I will definitely upvote and accept. Rest assured :)

Comment: 1. Each problem generates *4* subproblems, but in your recursion tree, you only draw 2 subproblems per problem (2 children per node).  2. A node should *either* be "unexpanded" (of the form "T(...)"), in which case it has no children (this corresponds to the LHS of the equation), *or* "expanded" (of the form "c*..."), in which it should have 4 children (this corresponds to the RHS).  3. In addition, the third row should have each occurrence of "n/2" replaced with "n/4".

Answer (score 1):

The formula for summation of a Geometric Series for elements a, ar, ar^2,...,ar^n-1 is given by

```
S(n) = a((r^n)-1)/(r-1)  // in case of r>1
```

The subproblem size for for a node at a depth i is n/(2^i). Thus, the subproblem hits size 1 when **`n/(2^i) = 1`**, or equivalently, when i=log<sub>2</sub>n.

Each level has 4 times more nodes than the level above, and so the number of nodes at depth i is 4^i.

Because subproblem size reduces by a factor of 2 for each level we go down from the root,each node at depth i,for i=0,1,2,...,log<sub>2</sub>n-1, has a cost of c*n/(2^i). Multiplying, we see that the total cost over all nodes at depth i,,for i=0,1,...,log<sub>2</sub>n-1 is **`4^i * c * n/(2^i)`** = **`(2^i)*c*n`**.

The last level at depth log<sub>2</sub>n has 4^(log<sub>2</sub>n) = n^(log<sub>2</sub>4) = (n^2) elements,each contributing cost T(1),which is θ(n^2).

Adding up the costs over all level,

> T(n) = cn + 2cn + 4cn + ... + cn*(2^log<sub>2</sub>n-1) + θ(n^2)
>
> ```
>  = cn*[(2^log<sub>2</sub>n)-1]/(2-1) + θ(n^2)
>
>  = cn*[(n^log<sub>2</sub>2)-1] + θ(n^2)
>
>  = cn*(n-1)+ θ(n^2)
>
>  = cn^2 - cn + θ(n^2)
>
>  = θ(n^2).    // OR    O(n^2) for an upper bound.
> ```

So, the complexity of your recursion-tree comes out to be θ(n^2). You can very well argue that it's complexity is O(n^2).

Comment: Good, except that "Each level has 2 times more nodes than the level above, and so the number of nodes at depth i is 2^i" should be "Each level has **4** times more nodes than the level above, and so the number of nodes at depth i is **4^i**".

Comment: @j_random_hacker- thanks, I corrected that. That was a typo while writing the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

From root to leaf, each level of the tree sees `n` halves, thus the tree has `log2(n)` levels.

The sum would then be:

```
n + 2n + ... + 2 ^ (log2(n)) * n
= n * (1 + 2 + ... + 2 ^ log2(n))
= n * (2 ^ (log2(n) + 1) - 1)
= n * (2 * n - 1)
= 2 * n ^ 2 - n
= O(n ^ 2)
```

All the analysis above assumes n is a power of 2, but as in the majority of the cases, the assumption matters not.

Comment: You can very well have a tighter bound on this too, like θ(n^2). Check my answer, though, that has always O(n^2) as an upper bound.

Comment: @shekharsuman This is already Theta(n^2) but I did not noted it. But of course, you did some more careful analysis and that works for all cases :-)

Comment: @ZiyaoWei- That's why I mentioned in your comment section so that you can have an edit in your answer if you wish. I'll upvote then.